# Prove: $C=\{(x,y):x>0,y<0, x+y>-1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ closed? open? bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> $$C=\{(x,y):x>0,y<0, x+y>-1\}$$

Is it sufficient to say that:

$f:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is continuous as a sum on linear and therefore continuous function.

The image $(1,\infty)$ is open set and therefore due to $f$ continuity so does $C=f^{-1}((1,\infty)))$?

And $C$ is not bounded because $\{A_n\}=(1+n,-1)\longrightarrow (\infty,-1)$ and there is not $r>0$ such that the norm of the point $||((\infty,-1)||<r$

Comment: not image. inverse image

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I first prove that the image is open and because the function is continuous so does the inverse image?

Comment: Yes, $(-1,\infty)$ is open by definition and hence so is its inverse image under $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit sloppy: You havent't specified $f$. But setting $f(x,y) = x+y$ we can see

$$C = ((0,\infty) \times (-\infty, 0)) \cap f^{-1}[(-1,\infty)]$$

which is open as the intersection of a basic open set of the product and the **inverse** image of an open set under the continuous $f$. So standard facts imply that $C$ is open.

This implies $C$ is not closed by connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but this is a big gun to use for this.

We can also note that for $n \ge 2$, $p_n := (\frac{1}{n}, -1 + \frac{1}{n})$ are all in $C$, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p_n =  (0,-1)  \notin C$, showing that $C$ is not closed under limits of sequences, so not closed.

Your non-boundedness argument is correct.

Comment: I have managed to show that $C$ is not closed (with the limit point as you did) but I could not managed to prove it is open (with the definition)

Comment: @gbox You can also use the two projections to see that the first set in my intersection is open. The definition using open balls can also be used but is a bit messier. Using $f$ is cleaner.